# ubuntu 16.06 lts, Booting become very slow after contracting swap area size

Tags: boot, swap, fstab

I want to delete dev/sda5 UUID which is pointed towards a non-existent partition, how do i do this?

```bsh
$ cat /etc/fstab

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=5bcf817f-f935-4b32-9a09-9fd55c78ea9e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=d9023442-81ce-4f8d-85e9-c29f195edf4e none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/FA989EF0989EAB21 /mnt/FA989EF0989EAB21 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/08F0A230F0A223C2 /mnt/08F0A230F0A223C2 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** If you want to remove the swap just remove or comment-out its definition from `/etc/fstab`. In your case this is the following line:

```bsh
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=d9023442-81ce-4f8d-85e9-c29f195edf4e none     swap    sw        0       0
```

**2.** If you want to setup another partition for swap area:

- Create the partition (or use `sudo lsblk` to find it). For the example, let's assume it is `/dev/sda3`.
- Execute the next command to format it as swap:

  ```bsh
  mkswap /dev/sda3
  ```
- Use the command `sudo swapon /dev/sda3` to activate it temporary, and then check whether it is successfully activated by `sudo swapon --show` and `free -h`.
- To activate it permanently first find the partition UUID by the command `sudo blkid /dev/sda3` and modify the swap definition in your `/etc/fstab` file.

**3.** If you want to use **swap file** instead of swap partition, that is more flexible approach used in the new Ubuntu versions:

- First create the file (let's assume it will be 16G large) and change its permissions:

  ```bsh
  sudo fallocate -l 16G /swapfile
  sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
  ```
- Next format it:

  ```bsh
  sudo mkswap /swapfile
  ```
- Activate it temporary and check:

  ```bsh
  sudo swapon /swapfile       
  sudo swapon --show          
  free -h
  ```
- Activate it permanently - add the following line in `/etc/fstab`:

  ```bsh
  /swapfile none swap sw 0 0
  ```

**4.** Further if you use swap within SSD, maybe you would want to minimise its usage:

- Tweak the values of `vm.swappiness` and `vm.vfs_cache_pressure`, for example ([reference](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04)):

  ```bsh
  sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10          # Frequency of swap usage: 0 - 100 / rare used - frequent used
  sudo sysctl vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50  # Cache flushing: 0 - 100 /  / rare flushed - frequent flushed
  ```
- Check the current values:

  ```bsh
  cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
  cat /proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure
  ```
- Make the changes permanent - add the following lines to the end of `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

  ```bsh
  nvm.swappiness=10
  nvm.vfs_cache_pressure=50
  ```